# Is there a way to have alphabet characters in uppercase in my javascript random string?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to generate a random string in javascript in the form [40 Alfanumeric charactors] [Date & Time] [Constant Organization Number] and so far this is what I have achieved.

```js
function randString(x) {
  var s = "";
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear() + '' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '' + today.getDate();
  var time = today.getHours() + "" + today.getMinutes() + "" + today.getSeconds();
  var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;
  var esd = " TSL12001749";
  while (s.length < x && x > 0) {
    var r = Math.random();
    s += (r < 0.1 ? Math.floor(r * 100) : String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(r * 26) + (r > 0.5 ? 97 : 65)));
  }
  return s + dateTime + esd;
}

document.getElementById("foo").value = randString(40);
```

```html
<textarea id='foo' style='width:100%;height:200px'></textarea>
```

I can't seem to have the alphabet characters in the random string uppercased and also strip off the first two characters in the year value. ie 2021, should read 21. Insights are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s.toUpperCase()` would solve the uppercase.

```
var date = String(today.getFullYear()).substring(2, 4)+''+(today.getMonth()+1)+''+today.getDate();
```

to get the substring of the year.